# Search through all files

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I tried pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice twice to "Search Everywhere" but it is not working as expected. I want to search through all files basically an equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> that not only searches through the current file but ALL files in ones project.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Despite its name .. it does not do plain text searches ... it's more of a combo of `Navigate | File`, `Navigate | Class`, `Navigate | Symbol`, `Help| Find Action` and search amongst Settings/Preferences. If you need `Ctrl+F` but in all files -- use `Ctrl+Shift+F` (Find in Path) as suggested by **lena**. But I've heard that they plan to have some improvements in next year or so in this area (no details as to what exactly might be changing)

Comment: we do plan to include text search in *search everywhere*; please folow  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124618 and linked tickets for updates

Answer (score 2):

Please try **Edit | Find | Find in Path** (`Ctrl+Shift+F`)
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.2/find-and-replace-in-path.html